# CoffeeScript - What does this strange "Return" occurrence mean?

Tags: javascript, coffeescript

Consider the following CoffeeScript:

```
$ ->
  if localStorage["Flag1"] isnt "Done"
    localStorage["Flag1"] = "Done" # Flagged on first page loading
  $(".start").click ->
    if localStorage["Flag2"] isnt "Done"
      localStorage["Flag2"] = "Done" # Flagged on first click interaction
```

Which compiles into:

```
$(function() {
  if (localStorage["Flag1"] !== "Done") {
    localStorage["Flag1"] = "Done";
  }
  return $(".start").click(function() {
    if (localStorage["Flag2"] !== "Done") {
      return localStorage["Flag2"] = "Done";
    }
  });
});
```

There are two strange occurrence of "return" being planted into the rendered JavaScript. What do they do, and how will they affect the running of the script? Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They won't affect the running of your script. The first `return` will return `$(".start")` (since the jQuery `click` method returns an instance of jQuery) from the DOM ready event handler. Since it's a callback that runs at a certain point, you can't really do anything with that return value.

The second `return` will return `"Done"`, after setting the `localStorage` property, but again, since it's returning from a callback (a click event handler this time) you won't be able to do anything with the returned value.

I believe CoffeeScript will `return` the value of the last expression in each function, which is why you see those `return` statements in the output. From the docs:

> Even though functions will always return their final value, it's both
>   possible and encouraged to return early from a function body writing
>   out the explicit return (`return value`), when you know that you're
>   done.